# Using AsParallel

Tags: c#

I have a list of EmpIds. I need to perform some operation for each of EmpId on this list.

```
void ProcessEmp(EmpId empId)
{
  // process the emp
}
```

Rather than looping through each employee Id one at a time, can I perform this operation using AsParallel? Basically I want to process each emp Id parallely.

Comment: How many items do you have in the list? How CPU intensive is the processing? I really *depends* on whether parallel is even faster. Have you done any timing? Is this your bottleneck?

Comment: In which list?  I see a function declaration in your example. If your list supports IEnumerable, you can use Parallel.Foreach.

Comment: @BrokenGlass There are around 80 items in the EmpId list. Noramal process takes around 20 mins to process these emp ID. I was wondering if it can be done faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than `AsParallel`, you probably want [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(ids, ProcessEmp);
```

Or if you don't like the method group conversion:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ids, id =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0}", id);
    ProcessEmp(id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I tried using parallel.ForEach. But its not giving any performance improvements. The programs still takes 20 mins to run

Comment: @rohit: Well without knowing what it's doing, we can't really tell what's wrong. Perhaps your bottleneck is some external resource, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Parallel.Foreach()` on them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg");
string newDir = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Modified";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newDir);

//  Method signature: Parallel.ForEach(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
Parallel.ForEach(files, currentFile =>
{
    // The more computational work you do here, the greater 
    // the speedup compared to a sequential foreach loop.
    string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(currentFile);

    bitmap.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
    bitmap.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(newDir, filename));

    // Peek behind the scenes to see how work is parallelized.
    // But be aware: Thread contention for the Console slows down parallel loops!!!
    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename,
    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    } //close lambda expression
); //close method invocation
```